# I can not open a default camera after I resume the App in java

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am working on an App that use camera for face recognition. But i have some problem when i resume my app the the app always crash.
This is my code Onresume Activity:

```java
@Override
  public synchronized void onResume() {
//    LOGGER.d("onResume " + this);
    super.onResume();;
    handlerThread = new HandlerThread("inference");
    handlerThread.start();
    handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

  }
```

This is my code in CameraActivity:

[CameraActivity.java](https://gist.github.com/seabnavin19/479cda227baa1d37e3876296c394a448#file-cameraactivity-java)

And this is the class that i used for recognize the face that extends from cameraActivity:
[Detector Activity](https://gist.github.com/seabnavin19/479cda227baa1d37e3876296c394a448#file-detectoractivity-java)

I forgot to show the erorr:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.samples.flironecamera, PID: 30923
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.samples.flironecamera.tracking.MultiBoxTracker.trackResults(java.util.List, long)' on a null object reference
        at com.samples.flironecamera.DetectorActivity.updateResults(DetectorActivity.java:728)
        at com.samples.flironecamera.DetectorActivity.onRestart(DetectorActivity.java:761)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestart(Instrumentation.java:1443)
        at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:8067)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performRestartActivity(ActivityThread.java:5188)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:243)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2270)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8125)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

And Another Erorr

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.samples.flironecamera/com.samples.flironecamera.DetectorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.startPreview()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: _"the the app always crash"_ Then the stacktrace from the crash is the natural place to start looking in for the reason of the crash.

Comment: hello, I already update the erorr

Comment: Ok, so you have a `MultiBoxTracker` that is `null` somewhere in some code that you haven't shown us. You need to either make sure that you have a valid object, or refrain from trying to access any of its members.

Comment: for MultiboxTracker class i just use it  in DetectorActivity.

Comment: Is the `CameraConnectionFragment` throwing its callback `ConnectionCallback` immediately? If its not then `OnResume` is called before `onPreviewSizeChosen` which is where you set  the `MultiBoxTracker`.

Comment: And I also got this erorr  :   void android.hardware.Camera.startPreview()' on a null object reference